# Problema con ngModel e input type=date

Tags: angular

Tengo un input an angular así:

```
 <input [ngModel]="pedido.fecha | date:'yyyy-MM-dd' : 'UTC'" placeholder="fecha" #fecha  type="date">
```

al cargar la página el input se rellena correctamente con la fecha que viene desde el objeto `pedido.fecha`, sin embargo si selecciono una fecha abriendo el datepicker el valor `pedido.fecha` sigue siendo el original y no el que he seleccionado en el datepicker, esto hace que al actualizar los datos me cargue la fecha inicial nunca la que he editado.

Comment: [(ngModel)]="pedido.fecha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mi problema se soluciona usando el objeto `$event` en conjunto con el disparador de eventos `(ngModelChange)`.

```
<input [ngModel]="pedido.fecha | date:'yyyy-MM-dd' : 'UTC'"  (ngModelChange)="pedido.fecha = $event" placeholder="fecha" #fecha  type="date">
```

`ngModelChange` escucha por actualizaciones del modelo en la vista, entonces cuando eso pasa asigno a la variable pedido.fecha el valor de `$event` que es el valor actualizado luego del cambio producido en la vista y eso soluciona mi problema.